# Writing Assertion For Objects

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to create an assertion method that the objects in question contain only scalar values (i.e., simple values like strings or numbers). It is OK to use JSON.stringify().

Example PASSED:

```
var expected = {foo: 5, bar: 6};
var actual = {foo: 5, bar: 6}
objectAssert(actual, expected, 'detects that two objects are equal');
// console output:
// passed
```

Example FAILED:

```
var expected = {foo: 6, bar: 5};
var actual = {foo: 5, bar: 6}
objectAssert(actual, expected, 'detects that two objects are equal');
// console output:
// FAILED [my test] Expected {"foo":6,"bar":5}, but got {"foo":5,"bar":6}
```

Here's my function so far:

```
function objectAssert(actual, expected, testName) {

 if(actual !== expected){
    console.error( "FAIL [" + testName + "] Expected \"" + expected + ", \" but got \"" + actual + "\"");
  } else {
    console.info( "SUCCESS [" + testName + "]");
  }
}
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: You can't use `===` or `!==` to compare the contents of objects. When it's comparing objects it just tests if they're at the same location in memory.

Comment: "Any idea what am I missing here?" — What makes you think you are missing something?

Comment: @Barmar `===` is Identity operation. it does not mean objects must be in same memory location. it means objects should be identical including there types.

Comment: @ShanilFernando In the case of objects, if they're identical then they're at the same memory location.

Comment: Strings and numbers are different, but object equality is by memory location.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are correct. I was confused with `scalar values`. My apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!==` to compare **objects** is wrong. What I suggest is, like you mentioned in the question, using `JSON.stringify` to compare both objects.

Example:

```
function objectAssert(actual, expected, testName) {

    _actual = JSON.stringify(actual);
    _expected = JSON.stringify(expected);

    if(_actual != _expected)
      console.error( "FAIL [" + testName + "] Expected \"" + expected + ", \" but got \"" + actual + "\"");
    else
      console.info( "SUCCESS [" + testName + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the json string objects:

```
if(JSON.stringify(actual) !== JSON.stringify(expected)){
   console.error( "FAIL [" + testName + "] Expected \"" + JSON.stringify(expected) + ", \" but got \"" + JSON.stringify(actual) + "\"");
} else {
  console.info( "SUCCESS [" + testName + "]");
}
```

Comment: I've seen this recommendation elsewhere (even the duplicate I linked to), but I think it's wrong. There's no guarantee that the order of properties will be the same when you stringify two objects.